# Better framework/abstraction for java concurrency

Tags: java, multithreading, data-analysis, fork-join

Concurrency in Java 5 and above definitely is better abstraction than dealing with raw threads.

I am really impressed with talk on fork-and-join and in memory data structures like parallel arrays go hand in hand. Unfortunately Java 7 left with bare bones of fork-and-join and missed data structures.

Would like to know if there are similar and well tested frameworks/abstraction to do aggregations for a huge data set efficiently.

Comment: the question is whether you want to stay in Java land. Scala provides a comprehensive Future implementation and immutable structures that deliver better concurrent properties. Also look at Spark, which is a framework (built on Scala) for in-memory (big) data analytics.

Comment: Ummm RxJava & Java 8 make this argument a stalemate-- but Scala easily wins a bunch of other arguments, the #1 being a lot less "ceremony" code.

Comment: Yes, scala/clojures/coreAsync are other frameworks suggested by functional guys. But a common platform with executors for both concurrent and parallel jobs would be best fit.

Answer (score 0):

I really think you should look at RxJava: https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki

"It extends the observer pattern to support sequences of data/events and adds operators that allow you to compose sequences together declaratively while abstracting away concerns about things **like low-level threading, synchronization, thread-safety, concurrent data structures, and non-blocking I/O.**"

...

"It is difficult to use Futures to optimally compose conditional asynchronous execution flows (or impossible, since latencies of each request vary at runtime). This can be done, of course, but it quickly becomes complicated (and thus error-prone) or it prematurely blocks on Future.get(), which **eliminates the benefit of asynchronous execution**.

RxJava Observables on the other hand are intended for composing **flows and sequences of asynchronous data.**"

Comment: Appreciate your answer. For my use-case Rx is good fit for computations, but not for blocking io jobs. I have a mix of both. like the stage1 to read the data from DB (coarse-grained), Stage2 process (fine grained), stage3 persist (coarse-grained). For coarse-grained thread pool executor is best fit with tunable number of threads, but for fine-grained forx-and-join with fixed number of threads (~ no. of cores) is good. The framework should fit both of these.

Answer (score 0):

Despite [RxJava](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava), which @user1500191 mentioned, I can just add [Akka](http://akka.io/) as another option for you.

> Akka is a toolkit and runtime for building highly concurrent, distributed, and fault tolerant event-driven applications on the JVM.

Comment: Akka may solve, but I feel the use-case I have in hand is too small to accommodate Akka. May by Rx, but it is best fit for half of my problem explained below.